# Windows environment variable that runs a script

Tags: python, windows

Is it possible to set a environment variable in Windows 7 that will run a python script when called? Couldn't do it when I tried.

Comment: What do mean by "addressed"? Accessing the contents of an environment variable doesn't trigger any action. It's simply a string in memory. The string could be a command line that runs a script when executed via the shell or `CreateProcess`.

Comment: How can i set it as a command line that runs a python script?

Comment: In a cmd shell, do `set "PythonScript=python script.py"` to store the command line `python script.py` in an environment variable named `PythonScript`. Then running `%PythonScript%` will run the command `python script.py`. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes! Will using setx do it perminentaly? And how does the PATH python envirpment variable work?

Comment: `setx PythonScript "python script.py"` adds the environment variable to the registry and updates Explorer. Subsequent cmd shell instances run from Explorer will see the new environment variable. You have to use `set` to modify the current shell.

Comment: `PATH` is a semicolon-delimited list of directories that get searched to find a filename to execute when the name is unqualified, e.g. "python.exe". `PATH` isn't used when the filepath to execute is fully or relatively qualified, i.e. when it contains a slash or backslash, e.g. `C:\Python27\python.exe` or `Python27\python.exe`.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to set an environment variable that calls a function when addressed. That's simply not something that environment variables can do.